# Module mpm_prefork is enabled - cannot proceed due to conflicts. It needs to be disabled first

Tags: php, docker, php-fpm, mpm-prefork, mpm-event

We've configured a Dockerfile containing the following code snippet:

```
    #############################################
#### Image containing compiled libraries ####
#############################################
FROM php:8.2-fpm-bullseye AS builder

#######################################################
############# START ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES #############

# Versions
ENV MEMCACHE_VERSION=8.0 \
    MEMCACHED_VERSION=3.2.0

############## END ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES ###############
########################################################

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    zlib1g-dev \
    zlib1g \
    libmemcached11 \
    libmemcachedutil2 \
    libmemcached-dev \
    libmagickwand-dev

RUN pecl install memcache-$MEMCACHE_VERSION && \
    pecl install memcached-$MEMCACHED_VERSION && \
    pecl install imagick

#
# APPLICATION COMPILE
#
FROM ubuntu:20.04
LABEL maintainer='Timothy van Exel <timothy@yoo.rs>'

#######################################################
################### START ARGUMENTS  ##################

# Symfony environment type e.g. dev
ARG SYMFONY_ENV_NAME

#################### END ARGUMENTS  ###################
#######################################################

#######################################################
############# START ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES #############

# Version
ENV UBUNTU_VERSION=20.04 \
    PHP_VERSION=8.2 \
    NODE_VERSION=14 \
    COMPOSER_VERSION=2.5.4

# Folders
ENV APP_FOLDER=/var/www/html \
    LOCAL_BIN_FOLDER=/usr/local/bin \
    IMAGICK_FOLDER=/etc/ImageMagick-6 \
    SO_FOLDER=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20220829 \
    APACHE_CONF_FOLDER=/etc/apache2 \
    SYMFONY_ENV=$SYMFONY_ENV_NAME

############## END ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES ###############
########################################################

WORKDIR $APP_FOLDER

RUN mkdir -p $SO_FOLDER && mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor && mkdir -p /var/run/apache && touch /var/log/supervisor/php-fpm_error.log && touch /var/log/supervisor/php-fpm.log
RUN touch /var/log/supervisor/apache2_error.log && touch /var/log/supervisor/apache2.log && chmod 777 -R /var/log/supervisor && chown www-data:www-data -Rf /var/log/supervisor
COPY --from=builder $SO_FOLDER/memcached.so /usr/lib/php/20220829/memcached.so
COPY --from=builder $SO_FOLDER/memcache.so /usr/lib/php/20220829/memcache.so

COPY --from=composer:2.5.4 /usr/bin/composer $LOCAL_BIN_FOLDER/composer

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install lsb-release ca-certificates apt-transport-https software-properties-common -y
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    git \
    curl \
    apache2 \
    vim \
    wget \
    sudo \
    memcached \
    zlib1g-dev \
    zlib1g \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libwebp-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    unzip \
    zip \
    ca-certificates \
    libmagickwand-dev \
    libmemcached11 \
    libmemcachedutil2 \
    libmemcached-dev \
    libz-dev \
    ghostscript \
    gnupg \
    supervisor \
    ssh \
    sshpass \
    ansible \
    php \
    php$PHP_VERSION-fpm \
    php-pear \
    php$PHP_VERSION-dev \
    php$PHP_VERSION-mysql \
    php$PHP_VERSION-pdo \
    php$PHP_VERSION-dom \
    php$PHP_VERSION-gd \
    php$PHP_VERSION-curl \
    php$PHP_VERSION-zip \
    php$PHP_VERSION-imagick \
    php$PHP_VERSION-intl

#RUN a2enconf php$PHP_VERSION-fpm && a2enmod mpm_event proxy_fcgi setenvif rewrite

RUN a2enconf php$PHP_VERSION-fpm && a2dismod php8.3 mpm_prefork && a2enmod  proxy proxy_fcgi setenvif rewrite
RUN apt-get install php8.2-fpm -y
RUN a2enmod mpm_event
RUN service php$PHP_VERSION-fpm start
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.3/install.sh | bash \
    && export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm" \
    && . $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh && nvm install $NODE_VERSION \
    && . $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh && nvm alias default $NODE_VERSION \
    && curl -sL https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/yarnkey.gpg >/dev/null \
       echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/yarnkey.gpg] https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list \
    && apt-get update && apt-get install yarn -y \
    && npm install -g npm@7.24.2 tributejs bootbox jquery-flagstrap i18next bootstrap@5 less less-loader less-plugin-clean-css webpack  yaml-loader webpack-cli js-cookie jquery@3.7.0 jquery-ui blueimp-file-upload jquery-ui-dist jquery-textcomplete @popperjs/core linkify-html linkifyjs @symfony/webpack-encore @babel/core @babel/cli @babel/preset-env lightbox2 uglify-js less dotenv
ENV PATH $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/bin:$PATH

COPY ../pipeline/$SYMFONY_ENV/config/php/ini_files/* /etc/php/$PHP_VERSION/fpm/conf.d/
COPY ../pipeline/$SYMFONY_ENV/config/php/ini_files/* /etc/php/$PHP_VERSION/cli/conf.d/
COPY ../pipeline/$SYMFONY_ENV/config/php/policy.xml $IMAGICK_FOLDER/policy_improved.xml
COPY ../pipeline/$SYMFONY_ENV/config/supervisord/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
COPY ../pipeline/$SYMFONY_ENV/config/apache/000-default.conf $APACHE_CONF_FOLDER/sites-available/000-default.conf
COPY ../pipeline/scripts/web_entrypoint.sh $LOCAL_BIN_FOLDER/web_entrypoint

RUN chmod +x $LOCAL_BIN_FOLDER/web_entrypoint

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["web_entrypoint"]
```

the dockerfile can also be viewed here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bd2a_LtwIrgb8vRMzoIf0gBQgp6RxEZHQauTZAppOFc/edit?usp=sharing

But on Thursday 11 January, starting from 21:00 after running `docker compose up --build` -d --force-recreate all of a sudden the following error started occuring. Note: This did not happen earlier this week, the whole week it worked just fine.

```
     => CACHED [webserver stage-1 11/21] RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive a  0.0s
 => ERROR [webserver stage-1 12/21] RUN a2enconf php8.2-fpm && a2enmod mpm_event proxy_fcgi  0.2s
------                                                                                            
 > [webserver stage-1 12/21] RUN a2enconf php8.2-fpm && a2enmod mpm_event proxy_fcgi setenvif rewrite:
0.129 Enabling conf php8.2-fpm.
0.131 To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
0.131   service apache2 reload
0.146 ERROR: Module mpm_prefork is enabled - cannot proceed due to conflicts. It needs to be disabled first!
0.146 Considering conflict mpm_worker for mpm_event:
0.146 Considering conflict mpm_prefork for mpm_event:
0.146 Considering dependency proxy for proxy_fcgi:
0.146 Enabling module proxy.
0.148 Enabling module proxy_fcgi.
0.150 Module setenvif already enabled
0.150 Enabling module rewrite.
0.152 To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
0.152   service apache2 restart
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c a2enconf php$PHP_VERSION-fpm && a2enmod mpm_event proxy_fcgi setenvif rewrite" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

Looks like something's wrong with mpm_event. I want to repeat that we haven't changed anything in the Dockerfile.

What we've already tried:

- Removing mpm_event, the build succeeded but the application logically doesn't work, because it requires mpm_event
- Updating Docker Desktop
- Disabling mpm_prefork, i get the following error: `ERROR: The following modules depend on mpm_prefork and need to be disabled first: php8.3`

Comment: I just took a look at the image `php:8.2-fpm-bullseye`. Please provide the rest of your Dockerfile up to the lines where the error occurs. The problem is most likely introduced earlier in your Dockerfile.

Comment: I added the dockerfile in my post. Here it is: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bd2a_LtwIrgb8vRMzoIf0gBQgp6RxEZHQauTZAppOFc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It would be far easier if you had just added it directly into your question, but  I'll have a look at it.

Comment: Ill do that too, no problem

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is the package `php`, which pulls the apache module with it which is in turn activated by default and also enables the `mpm_prefork` module.

If you only use php-fpm you don't need it at all. The `php-fpm` package installs everything it needs by itself.

Or you just disable the php module along with the mpm_prefork module.

Comment: side note: this image has a LOT of potential for improvement by consolidating RUN commands and removing packages that are not really needed.